# i cant recive any response from success: function(status)

Tags: ajax

This is my ajax part

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",            
        data: 'name='+ value,
        url: "master/Valid.jsp",
        success: function(status){                
              if(status)
                   return true;
              else
                   return false;
        }
    });
```

this is my valid.jsp page

```
    <%     
   String s1 = request.getParameter("name");       
    int check =  new DBDepartment().addDepartment(s1, 1);     
     if(check==1)
        return false; //in this line it shows error     
    %>
```

how can we send return the value either true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the $.ajax, But try to use $.post or $.get

### in login.jsp

//html

```
<form method="get" action="valid.jsp" id="login">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
    </p>
</form>
```

//ajax

```
$('#login').submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.get('valid.jsp',formData,processData);
        function processData(data) {
            if (data.trim()=='pass') {
                $('#formwrapper').html('<p>You have successfully logged on!</p>');
            } else {
                if (! $('#fail').length) {
                    $('#formwrapper').prepend('<p id="fail">Incorrect login information. Please try again</p>');
                }
            }
        } // end processData

    });
```

### in valid.jsp

```
<%
String user = request.getParameter("username");
String pass = request.getParameter("password");
if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("007")&&pass.equals("secret")){
    out.print("pass");
}else{
    out.print("fail");

}
%>
```

Comment: you cannot simply return true or false without the method.try to use out.print() instead